# Taking a variable from foreach when each time it executes

Tags: php, foreach

I have following piece of code in foreach loop.

```
foreach($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
{
  $guid = (int) get_input('guid');
  $file = new FileCreate($guid);
  $fileId = $file->guid;
}
```

What I want to execute is I want to take the value of $fileId every time when foreach executes and stores into a array variable , is it possible to do that ? Or else how we can keep the value of $fileID on first execution of foreach.

Comment: `$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]` be a `string`. And `$fileId[] = $value;` should help.

Comment: Create a array before.`$files = [];` and in your loop `$files[] = $fileId;`

Comment: ah haa, @cb0 ,,That's truly unexceptional  :) Thank you

Comment: @cb0 You don't need to define an empty array first, just simply do `$array[] = ''`. One does need to define a variable first before doing `+\-=` or `.=` asignments.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks for that tip. But I always like to define my variables before I assign sth. to them. Feels clearer and more correct to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
$myids = array();
foreach($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {
    $guid = (int) get_input('guid');
    $file = new FileCreate($guid);
    $fileId = $file->guid;
    array_push($myids, $fileId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is wrong because $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] is not an array and contains a text value. But if you want to have the first element of an array there is no need to do anything special, easily do like this:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    ...
}
$first_item = $arr[0];
$first_item_id = $arr[0]->id;
```